# How to make call on Tizen wear?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-emulator

I need to make call on Tizen wear. With call permission and following code I am launching call to any arbitrary number on a button click. Nothing happens so far on emulator.

```
static void Make_SOS_Call(void *data, Evas_Object *obj, void *event_info) {

app_control_h app_control = NULL;
app_control_create(&app_control);
app_control_set_app_id(app_control, "com.samsung.call");
app_control_add_extra_data(app_control, "number", "999");
app_control_add_extra_data(app_control, "launch-type", "MO");
if(app_control_send_launch_request(app_control, NULL, NULL) == APP_CONTROL_ERROR_NONE){
    dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, "starting call");
}

app_control_destroy(app_control);
}
```

How do I open call dialogue and make calls successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you read Tizen Common App Control page and try sample code for Call?
https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/app-management/common-appcontrols#call

`

```
app_control_set_operation(request, APP_CONTROL_OPERATION_CALL);
app_control_set_uri(request, "tel:0123456789");

app_control_send_launch_request(request, NULL, NULL);
app_control_destroy(request);
```

`

Comment: I'm trying to reach the same, but this always get me *PERMISSION_DENIED* errors on Tizen5.5 Wearable. Do you have any idea on how to overcome on this? "APP_CONTROL_OPERATION_DIAL" works, but "APP_CONTROL_OPERATION_CALL" gives the error. I have the `http://tizen.org/privilege/call` privilege.

Comment: You need to get "User Approval" for privacy privilege. Refer to this page: https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/security/privacy-related-permissions/